# Surjective Homomorphism induced from Image

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G, G'$ be two groups and $f:G \rightarrow G'$ a group homomorphism. Show that $f$ induces a surjective group homomorphism $G \rightarrow Im(f)$.

I know we need to show that it is a group homomorphism by showing $f(gh) = f(g)f(h)$. I also know to show that it is surjective, we must show $\forall y\in Im(f) $, $\ \exists x \in G $ such that $y=f(x)$.

I am having a hard time showing surjectivity. Is there anything specific we need to do in order to prove that this new homomorphism is induced from $f$?

Comment: ${\rm Im}\left(f\right)=\left\{f\left(g\right)|g\in G\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the definition of image, i.e, $\operatorname{Im}(f)=\{f(g)\in G'| g\in g\},$ so if $y\in \operatorname{Im}(f)$ then $y=f(g)$ for some $g\in G,$ therefore
$f:G\to \operatorname{Im}(f)$ is in fact surjective.

Answer (score 0):

The homomorphism induced by $f$ is the same as $f$ with Im$(f)$ as its range instead of $G'$.